# Angular reloads the page when my data request service to the API is executed. Only in Production

Tags: angular, typescript, apache, deployment, angular-local-storage

### The Problem

I have an angular application that works very well on the development server. The application uses localStorage (I know it's not the best) to store the user's JWT token

The problem comes when I put the application into production, for some reason when executing the service the page reloads and therefore I lose the localStorage and with it the JWT token of the user

### Environment

Apache Server + Debian 9 (Only in Production)
Angular CLI: 8.1.1
Node: 12.5.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 8.1.1

### Some code

I have managed to isolate the problem and have detected that it is the following code that makes this happen:

The function that triggers the API service:

```
    getPosts() {
        this.loading = true;
        this.mdpostsService.getFirsyMDPosts()
            .subscribe(data => {

                this.mdPosts = data['results'];
                this.mdPostsNextPage = data['next'];
                this.loading = false;
            });
    }
```

The code of the service that obtains the data:

```
    getFirsyMDPosts() {
        return this.http.get(`${environment.apiUrl}/mdposts/`)
            .pipe(map(r => {
                return r;
            }));
    }
```

To isolate the problem I created a button that triggers the function:

```
<button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="getPosts()">Ges Posts</button>
```

Comment: Nothing about this code alone would trigger a reload. There must be more to the problem. Is the button located in a form?

Comment: Actually, a reload should not clear you key on your local storage, this might come from somewhere else.

Comment: I think that's is a problem with the API, you are trying call a function that not exist or that is not acepted the parameter -Something like your problem crazyed me using .NET Core with an API that I send parameters that not validating- and you has no control the exceptions

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I have been working on other projects for a few days. When I use the django development server and the angular development server everything works perfectly without throwing any exceptions or forcing any reloads. Right now I am trying to use the API deployed on my production server together with the angular development server, to rule out API problems.

Comment: Indeed the problem seems to come from the API. Using the angular development server with the Django api deployed on the production server the problem appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally found the solution! After a few hours doing tests and looking at the hosts I could find that the problem was the authorization with WSGI Django.

The solution is simple, enable the [WSGI authentication headers](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/configuration-directives/WSGIPassAuthorization.html). Just put the following line in your Apache virtual host configuration:

```
WSGIPassAuthorization On
```